# clear content of a text file using TextWriter c#

Tags: c#

how can i clear all data of a text file using TextWriter object?

mt file name is: user_name.txt

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a TextWriter specifically?

Answer (score 9):

`FileMode.Truncate` will remove all text from the file and then open the file for writing.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\path\myfile.txt");
using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fi.Open(FileMode.Truncate)))
{
    tw.Write("write my new text here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would

```
File.Create(filename).Close();
```

work for you too?